# Grouping Series with different y-values in a scatterplot

Tags: excel, scatter-plot, series

I'm trying to group two different series that have different y values for the same x values in a scatter plot, however Excel doesn't let me do this. It wants me to put both categories in different series. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this is about my best guess as to what you want, though I fear is not right:

[image: SO17914877 example]

Please note that an image (even a rough sketch) is often helpful when requiring a chart and that the Excel version may be relevant.

Comment: Series two for example would have the two y-values for the same x-value. So it might have (1,7) and (1,2) for example.